# Android TV 11 locks database when app is in background

Tags: android, android-11, television

We have an app that is set as launcher in Android TV, We recently updated to OS 11 and we know have an issue:

Test Case:

Open another app(disney +)
View for 30 min to 1 hour
Close it
Open our app

**Behaviour:**
app tries to refresh token on resume and gets a 400 response that kicks you out to login

**Debug:**
Seems like the database is locked? we cant get the user info to send in api.

Is there a way to avoid the OS from killing our app in background? or not locking the database?

We did not have this issue in OS10 and lower.